# Firebase Crash Reporting not working on iOS real devices

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I got some problems with Firebase Crash Report on iOS. When I run my testing app on the simulator, it works pretty fine. But when I run it on a real device, nothing happen. Here is my sample code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCrash

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnClicked), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func btnClicked() {
    FIRCrashMessage("Cause Crash button clicked")
    fatalError()
}

}
```

Any suggestion to fix my problem? Thank you.

**Steps**

1. I install app from Xcode to a real device.
2. I stop the app by press "command + ."
3. I launch app from the real device and make it crash.
4. I relaunch the app.

Comment: I was having the same issue, take a look on my solution: [ANSWER LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160230/firebase-crashes-unreadable)

Answer (score 0):

- Did you add `FIRApp.configure()` on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
  method of your `appDelegate` file?
- When you relaunch the app(with the error commented) you see in
  console a message like `Crash message uploaded`?

also:

reset your OAuth credentials, run below command:

```
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
```

create new service account and make sure it has editor permission
Revise your script into below format:

```
   # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
   GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

   # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

Please make sure your app id and json file path are correct.