# Firebase crashes unreadable

Tags: ios, swift3, symbolicatecrash, firebase-crash-reporting

I have a  problem reading crash reports on FireBase, my reports look like:

[image: FireBase crash report]

I've already followed [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files) to symbolicate the stacktrace, got the same result.

- I'm using Xcode 8
- My app is made in Swift 3
- Already wrote "FIRApp.configure()" in my
  appDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, did make it crash, deattach the debbuger, fix the error, re-run the app, got message "Crash successfully uploaded", etc...
- I'm using pods(pod 'Firebase' and pod 'Firebase/Crash')
- I see in the FireBase console my events and crashes(just are
  unreadable)
- Installed the script for symbolicate automatically on build(see image):

[image]

Already downloaded FireBase provided examples(crash example does not include the scripting for symbolicate automatically)

Already followed this solutions(which didn't work):

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513092/upload-symbol-files)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121912/unreadble-errors-with-firebase-crash-reporting-on-ios-symbol-files)

and many others.

Already visited last 6 months links on stackoverflow and google groups with this problem.

Nothing has worked, help please!!!

Update#1: I received an email from firebase-support@google.com saying:

> reset your OAuth credentials

Didn't work, also I've been testing the script and the upload is correct, I'm starting to think is a Firebase bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, eureka!

I'm not sure about what was the mistake but I paste it here in case anyone is experiencig the same error:

1) I deleted my app on Firebase console

2) Create in Firebase console a new app with different name

3) Create and download a new GoogleService-Info.plist

4) Delete previous keys(`rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*`)

5) [Create new firebase crash configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwkC2.png)

6) Copy the obtained file on step 5 to my root path on my project

[image]

7) Enable all permissions in firebase scripts

```
chmod -R 777 ./Pods/FirebaseCrash
```

8) Added the script phase as mentioned in the firebase configuration link mentioned in step 5 (I noticed that my not working previous configuration had blank spaces in name, so I created a non blank spaces name)

[image]

And finally(I don't know exactly wy) is working:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh. this worked. I don't know too how it worked. but I got the line number :)

Answer (score 2):

Your upload script doesn't appear to be setting the `GOOGLE_APP_ID` var.It should something like:

**# Replace this with the `GOOGLE_APP_ID` from your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file**

```
1:xxxxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxxxxxx=1:my:app:id
```

**`# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded`**

"`${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "firebasecrash/firebasecrashreport.json`"

Here `firebasecrashreport.json` is name of ServiceAccount JSON file and firebasecrash is name of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Your upload script doesn't appear to be setting the GOOGLE_APP_ID env var. The upload run script step should look something like the following:

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:1234567890123:ios:1234abc567de89

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Users/yourname/yourproject/Your Project Name-5632e387efda6.json"
```

The below question I answered is a problem similar to yours.

[Firebase iOS multiple errors when uploading symbol files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617885/firebase-ios-multiple-errors-when-uploading-symbol-files/39646052#39646052)

Comment: I did, still got nothing

Comment: update to the latest pod (1.1.3), which has better swift support. additionally, there may be an issue where the firebase ui reports the crash as not symbolicated, even when it is (for swift only). what you want to look for is for stack trace lines that belong to your app, do those lines have filenames and line numbers.